# Conversion of JSON object to string problem

Tags: javascript, string, jquery-plugins, object

I am working with "jQuery Data Link Plugin".And it is collecting information from textbox and returning object.

I am trying to convert the object to string using "JSON.stringify(obj)".

using following function:

```
function formatObject(obj){

        return JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/,/g,'test').replace('{','{\n    ').replace('}','\n}')
    }


It returns the object value in this format:

{
    "name":"name"test"country":"country"test"age":"22"
}
```

I have to turn this object into this like an url,(example:"http://test.com/search?name=name&&country=test&&age=22")

How to convert that josn object into string url?

I have tried with several answer found by googling,unfortunately can not get as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually it is not needed i tried to replace "" by other "test" characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this the way to do it:

```
var t = {
    name : "name",
    country : "country",
    age: 22
};

var s="";
$.each(t,function(k,v) { s = s+k+"="+v+"&"; });

alert(s);
```

---

Play with it here:
    http://jsfiddle.net/tzdqr/

---

I guess you want `replace(/,/g,'&')` but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I want to convert the object from {
    "name":"name""country":"country""age":"22"
} to a string first like namecountry22,then want to convert it to a URL by appending url.The final output have to "http://test.com/search?name=name&&country=country&&age=22"

Comment: I don't believe that you want && I think you just want & -- see code above.